# Derby.js in an off-line packaged Chrome App?

Tags: racerjs

I've been working with AngularJS in an off-line [packaged Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps).

I came across off-line sync requirements that points to ShareJS and RacerJS.

Is it possible to use Derby.js in an off-line packaged Chrome App?

[AngularJS example App](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/gdrive).

Possible [CSP issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/issues/133).

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using the [derby-standalone](https://github.com/derbyjs/derby-standalone) module.

You can see an example of client-side only Derby in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/enjalot/pen/JpxGn) and another example which uses derby for only part of the [content of a site](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/630d636f1ae0db4e517c).

With derby standalone you can put a few lines of code to initialize a client-side app and render templates/components in the browser:

```
var app = derby.createApp();
app.registerViews();
var page = app.createPage();
document.body.appendChild(page.getFragment('body'));
```